# Backbonejs: check server periodically

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm trying to have my backbone application check the server as often as possible for updates to a model, similar to how twitter's site has new tweets that are automatically added.

My current setup is checking an external application through their api so I have no access to their server which leaves me to rely on the client side to do the checking without being too memory hungry, how can I achieve this?

Comment: need a websockets server for that, I need to do this without any server sadly.

Comment: oh yea gotcha, that's sad. than probably settimout in the self calling cycle with custom ajax

Comment: set up a timer and fetch,no magic in it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Javascript the only way you can really control timing is through setTimeout/setInterval; there is no "more sophisticated" mechanism, unless you count helper functions (eg. 'delay') which just wrap setTimeout/setInterval.

So, dmi3y's answer was correct.  However, since you mentioned Backbone in both the tags and in the description, here's a more Backbone-ish version...

```
var YourModelClass = Backbone.Model.extend({url: remoteUrl});
var instance = new YourModelClass();
var seconds = 5;
window.setInterval(_.bind(instance.fetch, instance), 1000 * seconds);
```

or, if you wanted to build it in to your class ...

```
var YourModelClass = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: remoteUrl,
    initialize: function() {
        var seconds = 5;
        window.setInterval(_.bind(this.fetch, this), 1000 * seconds);
    }
});
var instance = new YourModelClass();
```

It's also worth mentioning that setInterval returns an object which you can pass to clearInterval if you want to stop "polling".

P.S. Just in case you're not familiar with `_.bind`, it comes from the Underscore library, which Backbone depends on so you already have it.  All it does is fix `this` in place, so that when your timeout/interval function resolves, the `this` inside it will be the second argument to `_.bind` (and not `window`, which is what it would normally be).

Answer (score 2):

possible solution

```
(function IcallTheShoots(){
   console.log('am I?'); // any way you able communicate with server
   window.setTimeout(IcallTheShoots, 1500);
})();
```

why `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`, cause it makes sure next cycle will be called only when current is finished

Comment: This was the first solution to come to my mind also, just assumed it may had been a more sophisticated solution. Wasn't sure how smart it was to have a ajax call every minute...

Comment: mmm, than probably some sort of events? hover, scroll, click